# Push Xcode Project to TFS Git repository

Tags: ios, xcode, git, tfs, version-control

Trying to push Xcode project to TFS (Git repository), i created local repository for my project in Xcode, then install Git Credential Manager from GitHub, then trying to connect repository from Xcode by adding remote or connect to git repository, but the error message is "Authentication failed because the authentication credentials were rejected."
Would you please provide me with the correct steps.
Knowing that TFS 2015 & Xcode 8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution for me was to just add your local repository with command line.

```
git remote add origin ADRESSOFREPO
```

Afterwards you can use the version control in Xcode to push and pull

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2017 offers you SSH access. The earlier versions, like 2015, requires to setup SSL and Basic Authentication on the server. I guess that this is not properly configured for you.

The steps to setup SSL are described in details in the [docs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/setup-secure-sockets-layer).
[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli/blob/master/docs/configureBasicAuth.md) you can find what is required to configure Basic Authentication.

A couple of caveats:

- username should be entered in `domain\user` format
- do not enable Basic Authentication on the default non-SSL site

Comment: would you please provide me with the configuration of server? how to do it?
@Giulio-Vian

Comment: Added details to answer

Comment: Thank you, I will figure out what the problem with server configuration . @giulio-vian