# Authentication error when pushing toTFS git repository via Xcode 8.3

Tags: xcode, git, tfs

I am  able to perform all git operations via git command line (Terminal),But via Xcode causes an authentication error "Enter your credentials for the repository"

Comment: Working fine in Code 6.4 but not in Xcode 8.3

Comment: which version of TFS are you using？ Are you using SSL?

Comment: Version is tfs 2015 update 1 and not using ssl...just using repository url(clone)

Comment: If so, maybe you are using the windows authentication, which will not support in Xcode8.3 . Try to use basic authentication or ssl

Answer (score 0):

Since this work with Xcode 6.4 but not in Xcode8.3. This may happens cause XCode 7 doesn't support **Windows Authentication**.  It seems to be a common problem amongst users because there are many posts about it in google.

To make it all work you should **enable Basic Authentication** in your IIS TFS website on "tfs" virtual folder.

Be careful though because basic authentication sends your credentials over network as plain text. Highly recommend you use SSL in this case.

> The steps to setup SSL are described in details in the
>   [docs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/setup-secure-sockets-layer).
>   [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli/blob/master/docs/configureBasicAuth.md)
>   you can find what is required to configure Basic Authentication.
>
> A couple of caveats:
>
> - username should be entered in `domain\user` format
> - do not enable Basic Authentication on the default non-SSL site
>
> *[Source Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090304/push-xcode-project-to-tfs-git-repository)*

Also suggest you use **[Git Credential Manager for Mac and Linux](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux)**  to store credentials for Git version control.