# 'NTLM' authentication is not supported (-1) Xcode 13.3

Tags: tfs, xcode13.3, xcode13.3.1

After upgrading to Xcode 13.3+ i started receiving an error when pushing my code to git in TFS as the below meaning that my credentials are rejected:

```
'NTLM' authentication is not supported (-1) Xcode
```

I asked the question on Apple Developer Forums, one of the suggestions was to disable NTLM from TFS configs Windows Authuntication, We tried that which caused other teammates using Visual studio and browser to unable to login to TFS.

Previously in Xcode 13.2.1 or older versions the issue didn't appear at all, and Apple didn't mention such a change in Xcode release notes.

Comment: Git itself does not do anything with NTML (won't complain if you have it, nor if you don't). Xcode issues are specific to Apple and have nothing to do with Git. Meanwhile, NTML is outdated and now dis-recommended. [Related: NTLM went away between 6.4 and 8.3.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45229270/1256452). (Is this really an error, or is it just a warning?)

Comment: Xcode shows a username and password to authenticate with TFS ones filling the correct credentials and pushing the code , it returns an error. So the code cannot be pushed. It’s not a warning.

Comment: That's weird, given that Xcode dropped NTLM support so many years ago. Maybe try the Apple stackexchange site?

Comment: @torek , do u think i should move the question there ?

Comment: You're probably more likely to get a useful answer there. Hard to know for sure without trying (could leave the question here too).